# Add "New Event" link/button to Calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, newform

I am new to SharePoint, so please hang in there with me as I try to muddle through this.

I have a calendar that I would like to add a link to click on to add a new event to in the calendar view so that the users do not have to click on Events> New Event.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. Here is how I did it.

1. Click on Calendar
2. Change view to All Events
3. Click on "New Event"
4. Grab the url from the "New Event" form to use for url link.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking at a calendar styled view and mouse over any given day there should be a little link that says "add" that appears on that day. Clicking it will open the form for you to add an item to the calendar with related day you selected.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make a link for that or not? I know what you are going to say but I am trying to cut off questions about how to do this.

Comment: Yeah all lists have 3 forms pages to make them work. Display, Edit, and New. Just edit the view and add a content editor web part above the calendar and write some text that says "New Item" highlight it and insert a hyperlink for the text. The link will go to the "NewForm.aspx" page of your calendar. for example: https://<site>/list/calendar/NewForm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The url for Adding a new event inside a calendar should be as follow:-

```
/Lists/<<calender name>>/NewForm.aspx
```

you can edit the page and then add a link which have the above url. so when users click on the link a new event form will be opened...